# Attempting to send user input/randomly generated numbers into an Int array - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

Hi there I'm trying to make a lottery, generating 6 random numbers adding them to an array and then getting a users numbers and adding them to an array. This is what I've tried so far.

Heres my lottery class,

```
class Lottery {
    Random rand = new Random();
    // generating lottery numbers
    int cpnum;
    int[] allCpNumbers = new int[100];

    // bets placed
    int betsPlaced;
}
```

Here's my for loop to generate the random numbers and add them into my array

```
// printing lottery numbers
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    lottery.cpnum = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    lottery.allCpNumbers[i] = lottery.cpnum;
}
```

When printing the random numbers it gives me this

```
System.out.println(lottery.allCpNumbers);
```

Output:

[I@1b6d3586

I want it to be a set of 6 random numbers arranged like 3,13,10,43,12 etc.

Comment: JoeC - thanks for that link, I thought it was an issue with the memory used for the array, didn't think it was a problem with printing

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(loterry.allCpNumbers))
```

or

```
Arrays.asList(loterry.allCpNumbers).stream().forEach(System.out.println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put sysout inside for loop

```
     System.out.println(lottery.allCpNumbers[I])
```

Try below concept in your case

```
    String[] array = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

**Output:**

[John, Mary, Bob]